# Converting *.dwg to *.shp using FME pyfme or fmeobjects in bulk?

Tags: python, fme-form

I have many cad files with some important attributes, and I want deal with these vector data in ArcMap keeping attributes.

I want to convert this data to shapefiles in bulk.

I know FME software can do this, but I can't find way to do this in bulk.

I want to do this in the fme script language called pyfme so how can I use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing to ask is why you want to use Python. If FME in general can do something it doesn't make a lot of sense to recreate that programmatically.

Usually you only need to do extra development a) when you want to add specially developed formats or transformers, or b) when you need to integrate FME into another piece of software.

If you aren't doing either of those, then I would avoid using Python/pyfme right now.

As to bulk conversion, there are a number of ways...

1. When you run the translation you'll see a header line in the log like this:

   Command-line to run this workspace:

   C:\apps\FME2017.1\fme.exe C:\Users\imark\Documents\FME\Workspaces\ControlledSorter.fmw --SourceDataset_MITAB "C:\FMEData2017\Data\Parks\Parks.tab"

   You can bulk process by creating a Windows batch file script of some sort that runs the workspace using this command, passing in a different filename each time (here MapInfo, but CAD files for you)
2. Instead of using a batch file, create a separate FME workspace that reads a list of files (using the File/Directory Path reader). Then use a WorkspaceRunner transformer to run your main workspace, passing through a different filename each time.
3. Look for the source dataset parameter in the Navigator window and select all of the source CAD files there. Then FME will read all of your data. To get it back into a separate Shape file of the same name you'll need to do a Fanout. Check the properties for the writer feature type (the brown writing object on the canvas) and for the Shapefile name select Drop Down arrow > Attribute Value > fme_feature_type. This technique will work for small amounts of data, but I wouldn't try it on a lot of files since it is reading ALL of the data into memory at the same time.
4. Simply use Run > Batch Deploy on your initial workspace.

I hope this helps. #2 on the list is the preferred method because it's closest to something you can run on FME Server as well as FME Desktop. And check out the FME Knowledge Centre for specific examples of batch processing like this.

Comment: on the FME Server we use Directory Watcher for New and Modified files (CAD files) that covers Canada, any that are flagged are processed overnight ready for production work the next day.